# No user created after magento installation

Tags: database, installation, ce-1.9.2.0, user-roles

I installed fresh magento 1.9.2.0

just copied the magento folders and after that created database using cpanel.

now, i dont know what username and password to give in backend.

i followed [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82933/forgot-username-and-password-after-installing-magento-cms-on-my-local-server-xam)

i run `SELECT * FROM admin_user;` and than it showed :

[image]

if the user created already, than somehow we can change username and password, here there is no user created!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this sql script (where username is 'myuser' and password is 'password'):

```
LOCK TABLES `admin_role` WRITE, `admin_user` WRITE;

SET @SALT = "rp";
SET @PASS = CONCAT(MD5(CONCAT(@SALT, "password")), CONCAT(":", @SALT));
SELECT @EXTRA := MAX(extra)
FROM admin_user
WHERE extra IS NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO `admin_user` (firstname, lastname, email, username, password, created, lognum, reload_acl_flag, is_active, extra, rp_token_created_at)
VALUES ('Firstname', 'Lastname', 'email@example.com', 'myuser', @PASS, NOW(), 0, 0, 1, @EXTRA, NOW());

INSERT INTO `admin_role` (parent_id, tree_level, sort_order, role_type, user_id, role_name)
VALUES (1, 2, 0, 'U', (SELECT user_id
                       FROM admin_user
                       WHERE username = 'myuser'), 'Firstname');

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: i want to know why user didt created initially, just curious to know ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento I don't know for certain, but I think at installation there was a error.

Comment: may be you are right, as always i do some errors , Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can add admin with MySql query:

```
/* This is an example SQL script.
You should replace all the UPPERCASED variables.
The &lt;USERNAME&gt; variable can only be alphanumeric characters, and probably underscores (haven't tested)

You can either generate a password hash using the PHP code below,
or you can grab a password hash from the admin_user table from an
existing Magento install for which you know the admin password.
*/

/* Use the following PHP script to generate a salted password hash. You can also use a straight md5 hash, but it's much more easily brute-forced
&lt;?php $password = 'PASSWORD'; $salt = 'GF'; echo $hash = md5($salt.$password).':'.$salt; ?&gt;
*/

insert into admin_user
select
(select max(user_id) + 1 from admin_user) user_id,
'FIRST NAME' first_name,
'LAST NAME' last_name,
'EMAIL' email,
'USERNAME' username,
'HASH EXAMPLE: 178f29c8e4c6c801db90cd171e3b2b53:in' password, /* You can replace this value with an md5 hash */
now() created,
NULL modified,
NULL logdate,
0 lognum,
0 reload_acl_flag,
1 is_active,
(select max(extra) from admin_user where extra is not null) extra;

insert into admin_role
select
(select max(role_id) + 1 from admin_role) role_id,
(select role_id from admin_role where role_name = 'Administrators') parent_id,
2 tree_level,
0 sort_order,
'U' role_type,
(select user_id from admin_user where username = 'USERNAME') user_id,
'USERNAME' role_name
```

This is code from: [HERE](http://www.classyllama.com/blog/add-magento-admin-account-using-mysql-script) by Erik Hansen

Good luck! :)

Comment: sorry, i found error : http://prnt.sc/azoe33 . i found solution from other answer, thanks a lot for your support :- )

Comment: Just was need to read instructions :) but its ok if you resolve that :)

Comment: oh, sorry. I was in hurry. let me try in another database.

Comment: hehe..no problem, just check http://www.classyllama.com/blog/add-magento-admin-account-using-mysql-script, when you have a free time :)

Comment: i am free always :-) checking now.....

Comment: you are absolutely right, It worked fine. Thanks.